# Изменить информацию внутри торрент-файла

Tags: c#, файлы, torrent

Здравствуйте. Как можно изменить информацию внутри торрент-файла? Интересует поле «описание» и непосредственно название файла, содержащегося внутри `.torrent`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать данную [программу](https://github.com/GerryFerdinandus/bittorrent-tracker-editor/releases)

Репозиторий: https://github.com/GerryFerdinandus/bittorrent-tracker-editor

Или изменить онлайн: http://torrenteditor.com

Comment: Хоть из вопроса это и не очевидно, но, судя по тегам, автор ищет способ сделать это через код.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, спасибо)